# Passing an object from an Array list of objects to a method in java

Tags: java, oop, arraylist, methods, parameter-passing

I am creating many objects and storing in an array list. then i am calculating the annual balance for each "account" object through 'computeInterest' method. 
i need to return the object from the 'bankAccountDetails' and pass it to the 'computeInterest' method.

here i have created an array list of object "Account"

```
    public void bankAccount1Details() {
    for (int x=0; x<(x+1); x++){
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Please Enter The Following Details To create The Bank Account");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("The Customer Account Number");
        accountNumber = input.nextInt();

        for (int a = 0; a < accountDetails.size(); a++) {
            if (accountNumber == account.accountNumber) {
                System.out.println("The account number already exist");
                bankAccount1Details();
            }
        }
        if (accountNumber == 0){
            System.out.println("you have entered 0 for account number");
            break;
        }

        if ((accountNumber < 1000) || (accountNumber > 9999)) {
            System.out.println("Please Enter a valid Account number");
            bankAccount1Details();
        }

        System.out.println("The Customer Name");
        customerName = input.next();

        System.out.println("The Customer Account Balance");
        do {
            accountBalance = input.nextDouble();
            if (accountBalance <= 0) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid amount");
            }
        } while ((accountBalance <= 0));
        startingBalance = accountBalance ;

        do {
            System.out.println("Please Enter the Annual Interest Rate :");
            annualInterestRate = input.nextDouble();

            if ((annualInterestRate< 0.01) || (annualInterestRate > 15)){
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid rate");
            }
        }while ((annualInterestRate< 0.01) || (annualInterestRate > 15));

        do {
            System.out.println("please enter the monthly Automatic Deposit Amount ");
            monthlyDeposit = input.nextDouble();
            if (monthlyDeposit< 0) {
                System.out.println("ERROR: Withdraw amount, not valid");
                monthlyDeposit = input.nextDouble();
            }
        }while (monthlyDeposit <0);

        do {
            System.out.println("please enter the monthly withdrawal amount");
            monthlyWithdraw = input.nextDouble();
            if ((monthlyWithdraw < 0)) {
                System.out.println("ERROR: Withdraw amount, not valid");
                monthlyDeposit = input.nextDouble();
            }
    }while (monthlyWithdraw <0);


    System.out.println("The Account Password");
        passwordAccount = input.next().toCharArray();

        account = new BankAccount(accountNumber, customerName, accountBalance, balanceAfterTransfer, annualInterestRate,
        startingBalance, monthlyDeposit, monthlyWithdraw);
        accountDetails.add(account);
    }
    computeInterest(account);
}
```

Here i am passing the object "account" to the method "computeInterest".

```
int interestEarningYears;
double yearlyBalance = 0;
public void computeInterest( BankAccount account){

    System.out.println("please enter the number of years the interest to be earned");
    interestEarningYears = input.nextInt();
    for (int x=0; x<=interestEarningYears; x++) {
        yearlyBalance = accountBalance;
        double interest = ((account.annualInterestRate * yearlyBalance) / 100);
        yearlyBalance = yearlyBalance + interest;
        System.out.println("Ending balance for the year " +x + ": " + yearlyBalance);
    }
}
```

So, here when i create a more than 1 object, how do i calculate the annual balance?

I have a solution :- i can use this code as well

```
 for (int a = 0; a < accountDetails.size(); a++) {
        accountDetails.get(a).accountBalance....
        }
```

But i wanted to pass the object and compute the result for the needed account.

**i want rewrite the code for computeInterest() by passing object as the argument.**

*remember there can be many objects as needed*

Comment: Why not `computeInterest(accountDetails.get(a))`?

Comment: yeah that way is easy, but the project requirement says '• A computeInterest() method that accepts a BankAccount argument. Within the method, prompt the user for the number of years the account will earn interest. The method displays the ending balance of the account at each year for the number of years entered based on the interest rate attached to the BankAccount"

Comment: You didn't mention any of this in OP. What do you expect us for this? Do you want the code for the above? Edit the post and tell clearly what problem are you facing?

Comment: i want rewrite the code for computeInterest() by passing object as the argument.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels sorry if I am wrong in previous comments, but see my ranking and yours, i am just a beginner with few basic questions. each time when am to post a question I searched well, maybe i have missed them because the way i explain the title may differ. still, am trying my best. :/

Comment: @MohamedSajjadh: your question should show us where you're stuck, since without this, it is a duplicate of the thousands of "[how do I create an array list and pass it into a parameter](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+pass+arraylist+as+parameter+site:stackoverflow.com)" questions (please read the link), and your last one doesn't. You still can improve it you know. And also, please consider up-voting or accepting the answer below, or at least commenting on it. The poster would probably like to know that you read it and appreciate the effort.

Comment: @MohamedSajjadh: The ones who answer are not paid money, and your showing appreciation of their efforts is their *only* compensation.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels ya thanx, I didn't know that I am the one to pick the answer, so as I did to the last one you mentioned. maybe I can improve in future problems. anyway, thnxz brother!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this solution and please reconsider the code refactoring I have applied to your code, it is preferable to break down your code into sub methods instead of listing the whole logic in one long method.

It would be nice if you shared all classes next time, that helps us to figure out things very quick instead of assuming things.

I passed the whole list of accounts to the method instead of passing 1 account.

```
package stackoverflow.q1;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

Integer accountNumber;
String customerName;
Double accountBalance;
Double startingBalance;
Double annualInterestRate;
Double monthlyDeposit;
Double monthlyWithdraw;
Double balanceAfterTransfer;
BankAccount account;
Scanner input;
private char[] passwordAccount;
List<BankAccount> accountDetails = new ArrayList<>();


public void bankAccount1Details() {
    for (int x = 0; x < (x + 1); x++) {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Please Enter The Following Details To create The Bank Account");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("The Customer Account Number");
        accountNumber = input.nextInt();

        for (int a = 0; a < accountDetails.size(); a++) {
            if (accountNumber == account.accountNumber) {
                System.out.println("The account number already exist");
                bankAccount1Details();
            }
        }
        if (accountNumber == 0) {
            System.out.println("you have entered 0 for account number");
            break;
        }

        if ((accountNumber < 1000) || (accountNumber > 9999)) {
            System.out.println("Please Enter a valid Account number");
            bankAccount1Details();
        }

        System.out.println("The Customer Name");
        customerName = input.next();

        System.out.println("The Customer Account Balance");
        startingBalance = enterAccountBalance();

        annualInterestRate = enterAnnualIntrestRate();

        monthlyDeposit = enterMonthlyDeposit();

        monthlyWithdraw = enterMonthlyWithdraw();


        System.out.println("The Account Password");
        passwordAccount = input.next().toCharArray();

        account = new BankAccount(accountNumber, customerName, accountBalance,
                                  balanceAfterTransfer,
                                  annualInterestRate, startingBalance,
                                  monthlyDeposit, monthlyWithdraw);

        accountDetails.add(account);
    }
    computeInterest(accountDetails);
}

private Double enterMonthlyWithdraw() {
    do {
        System.out.println("please enter the monthly withdrawal amount");
        monthlyWithdraw = input.nextDouble();
        if ((monthlyWithdraw < 0)) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Withdraw amount, not valid");
            monthlyDeposit = input.nextDouble();
        }
    } while (monthlyWithdraw < 0);
    return monthlyWithdraw;
}

private Double enterMonthlyDeposit() {
    do {
        System.out.println("please enter the monthly Automatic Deposit Amount ");
        monthlyDeposit = input.nextDouble();
        if (monthlyDeposit < 0) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Withdraw amount, not valid");
            monthlyDeposit = input.nextDouble();
        }
    } while (monthlyDeposit < 0);
    return monthlyDeposit;
}

private Double enterAnnualIntrestRate() {
    do {
        System.out.println("Please Enter the Annual Interest Rate :");
        annualInterestRate = input.nextDouble();

        if ((annualInterestRate < 0.01) || (annualInterestRate > 15)) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid rate");
        }
    } while ((annualInterestRate < 0.01) || (annualInterestRate > 15));
    return annualInterestRate;
}

private Double enterAccountBalance() {
    do {
        accountBalance = input.nextDouble();
        if (accountBalance <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid amount");
        }
    } while ((accountBalance <= 0));
    return accountBalance;
}



//you can pass the whole list to this method 
public void computeInterest( List<BankAccount> accounts){

    int interestEarningYears;
    double yearlyBalance = 0;

    for (BankAccount account: accounts) {
        System.out.println("please enter the number of years the interest to be earned");
        interestEarningYears = input.nextInt();
        for (int x = 0; x <= interestEarningYears; x++) {
            yearlyBalance = accountBalance;
            double interest = ((account.annualInterestRate * yearlyBalance) / 100);
            yearlyBalance = yearlyBalance + interest;
            System.out.println("Ending balance for the year " + x + ": " + yearlyBalance);


            //set the account field in here 
            //I am not sure which field in the back account that has to store the yearlyBalance because you 
            //did not share all the calsses 
            //account.setXXXX(yearlyBalance);
        }
    }
}
```

}